# Using xPath & PHP to loop through an HTML and extract required attributes & text?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

I am trying to use **PHP** and **xPath** to extract various text and attributes from an **HTML** file.

The desired output is something like this:

```
 Item1 | level1 = AAAA | level 2 = aaa.com | text
```

I can construct the xpath however I am trouble creating the necessary loops to cycle through the file. **What would the best method to do this?**

Sample HTML - Sections and Subsections (item 1 to item 999):

```
 <div class=container1>
    <div class=item1>

          <div class=level1>
               <h1>AAAA</h1>
          </div>

          <div class=level2>
               <a href=aaa.com>text</a>
               <p>text</p>
          </div>

    </div>


          ..

    <div class=item2>

          ..

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've embedded the xml and used `loadXML()` instead of `load()`.

Please notice that it is a bit ambigous, which "text" you mean after the `href`, 
the text from href `<a href=aaa.com>text</a>` or the text from `<p>text</p>`.
My solution uses the text from href.

**Output**

item1 | level1 = AAAA | level2 = aaa.com | atext1

item2 | level1 = BBBB | level2 = bbb.com | btext1

**Solution**

```
<?php

// from your file
$xml = '
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="level1">
      <h1>AAAA</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="level2">
      <a href="aaa.com">atext1</a>
      <p>atext2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item2">
    <div class="level1">
      <h1>BBBB</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="level2">
      <a href="bbb.com">btext1</a>
      <p>btext2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
';

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
//$xmldoc->load('yourFile.html');
$xmldoc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

foreach($xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'item')]") as $node){

    echo $node->getAttribute('class') . ' | '; // item 1

    $div = $node->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach($div as $i) {

        if($i->getAttribute('class') === 'level1') {
            echo $i->getAttribute('class') . ' = ' . $i->nodeValue . ' | ';
        }

        if($i->getAttribute('class') === 'level2') {

            echo $i->getAttribute('class') . ' = ';

            foreach($i->childNodes as $node){
                if($node instanceOf DomElement && $node->hasAttribute('href')) {
                    echo $node->getAttribute('href') . ' | ' . $node->nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<br>';
}

// Item1 | level1 = AAAA | level 2 = aaa.com | text2
?>
```